# Prove: if $A$ is a closed ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ then $int(A)$ is an open ball

Tags: general-topology

Let $A$ be a closed ball, $A=\{x:||x-a|\leq r\}$, Lets take $y\in A$ such that $\{y:||y-a||<r\}$ by definition all these elements of the group form an open ball $B$

How should I continue?

Comment: Consider some $x$ in $A$. Can you find an open ball in $A$ centered in $x$ if $||x-a||<r$? What if $||x-a||=r$?

Comment: The sentence "Lets take $y\in A$ such that $\{y:||y-a||<r\}$" makes no sense. You probably mean "Let's take $y\in A$ such that $\|y-a\|<r$".

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be your closed ball, of radius $r$. Let $B=\{y\in A:||y-a||<r\}$. This is an open ball, and we'd like to show that $\text{int}(A)=B$. Do this with simple set inclusions: $B$ is open because open balls are, and $B\subseteq A$ hence $B\subseteq\text{int}(A)$. For the other inclusion, let $y\in\text{int}(A)$, and try to show $y\in B$.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

1. An open ball $B(y,r_y)$ is included in an open ball $B(x,r_x)$ if and only if the distance $d$ between $x$ and $y$ satisfies $r_y+d<r_x$.
2. To prove the former, use the triangle inequality.